# WSS3.0 Wiki workarounds

Tags: wss-3.0, wiki

I've created a Custom List which performs a Lookup to the Title field of a Wiki Library. Is there any way I can hack together a way to then display items from the Custom List on the Wiki pages, which are associated with the current article via the Lookup?

Without the publishing model (I am working with WSS3) I'm at a bit of loss as to how I could deliver this. Any help would greatly appreciated, rendering you a gentleman (or lady) and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [display related info](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo&referringTitle=Documentation) operation of the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) library.

> SPDisplayRelatedInfo is a function in the jQuery Library for
>   SharePoint Web Services that lets you display information which is
>   related to the selection in a dropdown. This can really bring your
>   forms to life for users: rather than just selecting bland text values,
>   you can show them images and links that are related to their choices.

Comment: Looks promising @PirateEric, is there a way to embed this code in the template for a wiki library/in existing wiki pages?

Comment: The wiki pages are a bit funny from regular forms and web part pages.  I believe that there is, but I'd have to crack open a wiki in SPD to see what's going on.